# read_table with minus zero (-0) in R

Tags: r, file

I am reading a .txt file in R with read_table.

This file contains multiple columns, where three of them corresponds to 'hh mm ss'. Since 00 00 00 corresponds to midnight, any value before that is negative, as in, -00 30 00 corresponds to 30 minutes to midnight.

Here is some of the .txt data:

```
-00 53 30
-00 53 05
-00 52 43
-00 52 20
 00 02 25
 00 02 37

data <- read.table('data.txt',header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Output data:

```
 00 53 30
 00 53 05
 00 52 43
 00 52 20
 00 02 25
 00 02 37
```

The problem is I need it to be a "negative zero".
How can I overcome this?

Comment: Welcome to SO: Please help us help you by providing your question in [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) format. You can provide us the code block that you are using to read in the data, and even a subset of the data in question with both classes of input, as well as what you want as output.

Comment: use `readLines()` to read the entire line as a character value. Not sure how you want to parse these rows or what you want to do with them after import.

Comment: You should also be able to specify the `colClasses` parameter to `read.table`.  You can specify that the columns are characters, not numeric values.

Comment: This might help, although I need to average the times :)